# When IE will stop supporting the document mode 7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, ie11-developer-tools

I want to know, till what time will IE team supports the backward compatibility using the emulate tag for example ie11 to ie7 using
`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Microsoft is no longer making changes to Internet Explorer (except for security updates), this will continue to work for the foreseeable future.

Comment: Thanks for your input, do we have any information to confirm this or in any blog they are saying, because i need to convey the same to my client

Comment: @BhaskaraArani. There will be no further development on Internet Explorer , except for security patches. So it's safe to tell your client functionality won't change anymore. If for some strange reason Microsoft would decide that they need to make changes to the browser anyway, then you can't really be held accountable by your client for software not working anymore. They should update their software anyway so you don't need 'hacks' like document mode.

Comment: Thanks @LuudJacobs for the upate